# how to define the complex model in spyne?

Tags: soap, spyne

I have received such a soap message from a soap client. But i do not know how to define a service based on spyne to handle this soap message.

```xml
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:sde1="http://www.aglaia-gmbh.de/xml/BaSS_SOAPd/"
xmlns:sde2="http://www.aglaia-gmbh.de/xml/2013/05/17/BaSS_SOAPd.xsd">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <sde2:notification_message>
        <sde2:startup_notification
            mac_address="00:0B:91:A0:0C:34"
            notification_ID="1"
            serverTask_ID="0"
            timestamp="2022-01-01T04:05:38.675327+00:00"
            ip_address="192.168.90.201"
            xml_version="http://www.aglaia-gmbh.de/xml/2013/05/17/BaSS_SOAPd.xsd"
            paramset_version="">
            </sde2:startup_notification>
        </sde2:notification_message>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

```py
from spyne import (Application, rpc, ServiceBase, Iterable, Integer, Unicode, ComplexModel, XmlAttribute)
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11, Soap12
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication

class Request(ComplexModel):
    startup_notification = Unicode
    mac_address = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    notification_ID = XmlAttribute(Integer)
    serverTask_ID = XmlAttribute(Integer)
    timestamp = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    ip_address = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    xml_version = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    paramset_version = XmlAttribute(Unicode)

class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
    def SayHello(self, name, times):
        for i in range(times):
            yield 'Hello, %s' % name

    @rpc(Request, _returns=Unicode, _body_style='bare')
    def notification_message(self, startup_notification):
        print(startup_notification)
        return 'OK'

application = Application([HelloWorldService],
                          tns='targetNamespace',
                          in_protocol=Soap12(validator='soft'),
                          out_protocol=Soap12()
                          )

wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
```

it does not work. And as they say, how do I define the parameters of this receive function?